# Scale drawableLeft in button with text

Tags: android, button, drawable, scaling

I have a button with text and a drawable on the left. Is there any way I can make that drawable scale to it's appropriate size (fill button's height) while keeping its aspect ratio?

Relevant excerpt from my layout:

```
        <Button 
            android:text="@string/add_fav"
            android:id="@+id/event_fav_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_yellow"/>
```

Comment: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize an image on basis of the dimension of a Button, use `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods to get the size of the button and use following function to resize image for Button:

### Resizing a Bitmap:

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

int width = bm.getWidth();

int height = bm.getHeight();

float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

// create a matrix for the manipulation

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// resize the bit map

matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// recreate the new Bitmap

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

return resizedBitmap;

}
```

---

Now use this resized image for your button.
[Reference](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/)

Answer (score 0):

Can U create a button (containing all) like that in graphics.

Or U can try with this>>
1. Take a Layout(Relative or Linear) with width and height same as your button size.
2. Now put the image view  and text view within that. 
3. Make layout clickable..

Comment: This is a bad idea when considering different language support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function made of following code in `onCreate()`:

```
    //get left drawable
    Drawable drawable = btn.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
    int imgHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int imgWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    //for dpToPixel look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6327095/2306907
    float scale = (float) (dpToPixel(40)) / imgHeight;
    Rect rect = drawable.getBounds();
    int newWidth = (int)(imgWidth * scale);
    int newHeight = (int)(imgHeight * scale);
    rect.left = rect.left + (int)(0.5 * (imgWidth - newWidth)); 
    rect.top = rect.top + (int)(0.5 * (imgHeight - newHeight));
    rect.right = rect.left + newWidth;
    rect.bottom = rect.top + newHeight;
    drawable.setBounds(rect);
```

or have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32479741/2306907), which tries to give an "universal" solution.