# Android : Help me To resize drawable's image on Button

Tags: android, image, drawable

i design a Button combine between `image.png` and `text` . i have been searching but still can't get like what i want.

for selector :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <!--apply button background transparent, full opacity-->
            <solid
                android:color="#00ffffff" />
            <!--make button border solid color, nontransparent-->
            <stroke
                android:color="#ffffff"
                android:width="2dp"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="2dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
                android:topRightRadius="1dp"
                />
            <padding
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

for button.xml

```
<Button

            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Guest"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ico_arrow_white_xhdpi"
         android:background="@drawable/button_guest_register_login_border"/>
```

this image that i want to resize :

[image]

Thank in advance

Comment: You can use android:drawablePadding attribute and set the padding of right drawable image

Comment: @AndiGeeky : sorry, i mean, like what i want to design in my apps (maybe my grammar made you misunderstand )

Comment: @Hashir Sheikh : can't worked. Would you mind to explain more?

Comment: Opps, sorry! my mistake this attribute help u to set position of cross image.

This link help you to resize ur image : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623906/scale-drawableleft-in-button-with-text

Comment: @Hashir Sheikh : okay thanks! but, is this working for `.png` extension ? sorry! i haven't try using like this before.

Comment: Yes , this will work for png extention, You can retrive the bitmap from drawable folder using BitmapFactory.decodeResources(getResources(),R.drawable.test.png)

Comment: Also you have to set drawable right from programmatically, see this link for this point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button

Comment: @HashirSheikh : Thanks a lot! other inspiration for me ^^..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of button you can use this and implement click event of framelayout.

```
   <FrameLayout 
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
         android:background="<Your Background image>">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="<Your text>"                   
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:src="<image drawable>" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I have one solution now, but i still prefer to use on `Button`

Comment: Try this :-    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s_vit);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5), 
                         (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
Button btn = findViewbyId(R.id.yourbtnID);
btn.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);

Comment: why when i clicked the FrameLayout there is no response like Button (when you click)?

Comment: Which type of response can you specify?