# Unable to scale Drawable with ScaleDrawable

Tags: java, android, drawable

Scaling with ScaleDrawable is not working for me.
The drawable is remained in the same size.

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);        
Drawable d = layerDrawable.getCurrent();
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(d, 0, 0.01f, 0.01f); 
return sd.getDrawable();
```

What i need to do to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the [level](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setLevel%28int%29):

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);        
Drawable d = layerDrawable.getCurrent();
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(d, 0, 0.01f, 0.01f); 
sd.setLevel(8000);
return sd;
```

The level ranges from 0 to 10000: at 10000 it is full size, at 0 it does not appear at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable.html) for `ScaleDrawable`, you will see that the `getDrawable` method returns the base drawable. That is, it returns `d` in your case. You should just return `sd` as it is already a `Drawable`.