# Is there any way I can make images on buttons auto-resize to fit the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, autoresize

So I have four buttons, all of them use match_parent for both height and width. I use the "drawableTop" attribute to have images within the buttons themselves and I'd like to make it so I don't need separate images for each resolution. Here's a portrait screenshot I took. The landscape one will come in a bit.

[image: Buttons-Portrait]

So this looks fine and all but I only have 4 different image resolutions and trying them out on my phone didn't yield positive results. Is there any way I can just have one larger image, say in just "drawable" and have it shrink to fit in all resolutions? If not, what would I have to do? I currently cover hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, and xhdpi but I'd like to cover all bounds. What other densities exist?

If I can achieve the auto-resizing, I also wouldn't have to disallow users from using Landscape:

[image: Buttons-Landscape]

Also, here's the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCamera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bGallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPlants"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not easily possible with a `Button` with a drawable background, as drawable's don't scale with the view.

I believe you could do it if you changed the `Button`s to `ImageButton`s, which offer more options for scaling images.

The ImageButton class exposes the `android:scaleType` attribute, with which you could use `centerInside`, would shrink the image to fit into the bounds of the ImageButton.

Also with `ImageButton` you should define the image with `android:src` instead of `android:drawable`.

I'm not sure if there's a way to set text on an ImageButton though. You may need a more advanced layout consisting of an ImageView and TextView in a LinearLayout, and then treating that LinearLayout as the button (add onClick, etc).

Comment: Yeah, I researched this and saw scaleType would fit my needs but it doesn't seem like there's a way to put text on ImageButtons like how I have it in the image above, right? :/

Comment: @BackpackOnHead - No, I'm afraid not. You may find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton

Comment: @TIm - Yeah, that's where I learned to do the drawableTop. It doesn't look like I can do exactly what I need to but perhaps the LinearLayout option may be the route I need to take. I'll wait for other solutions, but for now yours seems to be the best. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim - Your method works perfectly. I used the standard button xml for the LinearLayout's background drawable, so it gets all of the animations as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have one larger image and have it shrink to fit in all resolutions. You can achieve this autosizing programmatically. Have a look at `DroidUtils.scaleButtonDrawables` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32479741/2306907).