# why isn't ScaleDrawable displayed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm defining a `ScaleDrawable` in XML according to the Android developers site example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/sign_ui_text_line"
    android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:scaleHeight="80%"
    android:scaleWidth="80%" />
```

I define this as the background of an `EditText`

for some reason the drawable isn't displayed (but the `EditText` view changes it's size according to the definitions).

why doesn't it display ?

how can I scale a drawable to be used as a background ?

Answer (score 0):

ScaleDrawables seem to require some workarounds in order to work properly, from the sounds of things.

See [Zeh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13706836/1542891) to a similar question.