# Changing the drawable size inside a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-button, android-image

I want to create a `Button` like this:

[image: Button Example]

**Here is my code:**

```
<Button
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:text="Play Game"
android:background="@drawable/ronaldo"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/messi" />
```

But the `messi.jpeg` is too large, and it doesn't show the text in this situation. How to decrease the image size to fit the button?

May anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Yah, already, but the image is not fit as the way I want to.

Comment: Look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538021/how-can-i-shrink-the-drawable-on-a-button

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Solution 1:

Adding a drawable to a button has very limited functions. You can't change the drawable size, so the best way to fix it is to add a button with an image view beside it in a linear layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/ronaldo"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Play Game"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/messi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Solution 2:

You can also do the following if you prefer this one, but you will have to add onClickListener() for each one of them:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/ronaldo"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Play Game"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/messi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Solution 3:

As you have suggested in the comments, you would do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/ronaldo">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:background="@null" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Play Game"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/messi" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have already done like this way, but is look not very nice and whenever to process something, we must have to process this "small button". That's not very good way

Comment: This is the only way to do it. If you want a better but harder approach, you can use 9-patch images. Google it for more help. Hope that helps.

Comment: @khuong291 Please also check my updated answer. It might be what you exactly need.

Comment: How about this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538021/how-can-i-shrink-the-drawable-on-a-button

Comment: @khuong291 This is what I exactly did. No difference.

Comment: What's the problem with the second solution? Did you try it?

Comment: The issue here is: I want to create a button that cover the text and the image (easily to control) , but the image is not fit the size as I want to, how about create a TextView, an ImageView in the under layout (must blure them) and a Button in the upper layout.

Comment: @khuong291 Nice idea. Please check solution 3 in my updated answer.

Comment: Nice, you are the wonderkid :P. Can I add friend with you on Skype?

Comment: Glad it solved your problem! Can you please accept my answer if it helped you? Unfortunately, I don't have skype, but you can always email me if you need any help from my stackoverflow profile. :)

Comment: Can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656588/quiz-game-set-the-correct-answer-onto-random-button

Comment: You removed the question?

Comment: Btw, how to play a lot song in 1 activity, If the 1st Song ends, the 2nd Song begin, and so on. How to do it?

Comment: You should better ask another question because this will be another question. You can link me to it here.

Comment: already open a new topic, you can visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678910/how-to-play-a-lot-of-sound-in-background-of-activity

Answer (score 37):

If you are using API >= 23, you can put the drawable resource within a XML file like this
**messi_smaller.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/messi"
        android:width="smaller_width_in_dp"
        android:height="smaller_height_in_dp">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You must make sure to keep the drawable ratio when you set the width and the height. And just use this drawable in your button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Play Game"
    android:background="@drawable/ronaldo"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/messi_smaller" />
```

By this way, you can change the drawable size just in xml code

Comment: finest and smart, this is the correct solution! Thanks

Comment: Excellent solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the `button` and made a layer like a `button`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="go_map"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_m0"
            style="@style/menu2img"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ico_m0" />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            style="@style/menu2text"
            android:text="@string/men_map" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

you can use a **RelativeLayout** like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ronaldo">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="play game"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/messi"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, I want only 1 Button that have the Text and the Image Inside it.

Comment: whats the problem of using this way?

Comment: Not Problem here, but whenever to process something, we must have to process this "small button". That's not very a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
ViewTreeObserver vto = button.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                button.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                //scale to 90% of button height
                DroidUtils.scaleButtonDrawables(button, 0.9);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling multiple screen sizes, creating alternative version for given screen (drawable-mdpi folder and so on...) can be solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing a vector directly you can use the following:

```
<vector android:height="30dp"  android:tint="#00FF41"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="30dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M20,6h-8l-2,-2L4,4c-1.1,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L2,18c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L22,8c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM20,18L4,18L4,8h16v10zM8,13.01l1.41,1.41L11,12.84L11,17h2v-4.16l1.59,1.59L16,13.01 12.01,9 8,13.01z"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For API >= 23 and for `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`(FAB) , you can put the drawable resource (SVG) within a XML file with the path: `File/New/Vector Asset` and save the file under the name for example: ic_water_white_24dp.xml

and add `app:maxImageSize` attribute to the FAB:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAddProduct"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:maxImageSize="40dp" // add this line to increase the icon inside the fab
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_water_damage_white_24dp" />
```

[image: Before] [image: After]

Answer (score 0):

Try using vector files instead of JPEG. Also, you can even convert `jpeg` to `svg` format too.
Once you import svg file into Android Studio project, you are going to see `<vector>` resource then just change the size as you want by `width`, `height` attributes.
`viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` is to set size for drawing on virtual canvas.

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="20dp" <!-- fix the size here -->
    android:height="20dp"
    android:viewportWidth="40"
    android:viewportHeight="40">
  <path .../> <!-- your shapes are here -->
  <path .../> 
</vector>
```