# How to play a lot of sounds in background of an activity?

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer

For example, I want to play 3 songs. When the 1st song ends, the 2nd song begins, and when the 2nd song ends, the 3rd song begins, and when the 3rd song ends, the 1st song begins again and so on. Is the `mp.setOnCompletionListener` used here?

Comment: Hussein El Feky is correct, however, I'd recommend playing music as a service in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. You can do something simple like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp1, mp2, mp3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music_1);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music_2);
        mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music_3);

        mp1.start();

        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp2.start();
            }
        });

        mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp3.start();
            }
        });

        mp3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp1.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will play mp1 and onCompletion of it, it will play mp2, and onCompletion of mp2, it will play mp3, and onCompletion of mp3, it will play mp1 again and so on...

Comment: I want to use this way in 1 activity, other activity will not play these music, how to do that?

Comment: You can take use of onPause() and onResume() methods to achieve what you want, but it depends on your app lifecycle. Does the user have the ability to go back to this activity where the songs were being played? Or do you always call finish(); on that activity when starting another activity? If you need more help, please tell me your app lifecycle regarding this activity.

Comment: ***Just clarifying what I mean:*** If you are going to start another activity without finishing this activity, you can write in onPause() **"mp.pause();"** and restart it from onResume(), but if you are going to start another activity and finish this activity, you can call **"mp.release();"** in onPause() method.

Answer (score 1):

First declare the 3 MediaPlayer files:

```
MediaPlayer song1;
MediaPlayer song2;
MediaPlayer song3;
```

Then initialize the `MediaPlayer` objects:

```
song1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.exampleSong1);
song2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.exampleSong2);
song3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.exampleSong3);
```

Now start the first Media file with

```
song1.start();
```

Now with every instance created you should add to every `MediaPlayer` object a `setOnCompletionListener` like this:

```
song1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        song2.start();
    }
});
```

Do the same for the Second and Third MediaPlayer files:

```
song2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        song3.start();
    }
});

song3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        song1.start();
    } 
});
```