# How to change a drawableLeft icon size?

Tags: android

I have look for some solution [how to change a drawableLeft icon size on a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998914/how-to-change-a-drawableleft-icon-size-on-a-button), but it's not work for me .

My button layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/twoButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eceef5"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goToPersonalPage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawable_left_green"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:drawablePadding="-10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_oval"
            android:text="ICon"
            android:textColor="#29395e"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logOutPersonal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_oval"
            android:text="@string/logOut"
            android:textColor="#29395e"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I adjust the size of button by `drawable_left_green.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    // I think it should be more smaller if i set 15sp.
    <item
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:width="15sp"
        android:height="15sp"
        />

</layer-list >
```

When i compile the project it (photo2)doesn't look like the preview layout(photo1):
[image]
[image]

I can't figure out why it's happen like this , some one can teach me how to fix it ?
Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: consider this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538641/7104450

Comment: And you can also use fancy button for this type of task its very good library here is the link https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons

Comment: My Android Studio's preview looks like the second image.

Comment: If you set 15sp that your preview should like the first image .

Comment: @ShashankVerma , thanks for your help , i find the answer from the link , i did not expect how complicated if i want to adjust the drawableLeft size.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538021/how-can-i-shrink-the-drawable-on-a-button

Comment: @徐博俊 okay bro no prob....its very good my comment help you....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the answer from my link but i thought to give you in answer so it will help others.

**Setting scaled drawable in code**

```
 Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(YourActivity.this,R.drawable.akshay);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5), 
                     (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
Button btn = findViewbyId(R.id.yourbtnID);
btn.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```

Comment: require API 23 and higher ?

Comment: is it saying Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.akshay); getDrawable depricated @sasan

Comment: thank u for attention , I'll try this

Comment: what does this code do ?

Comment: Did you see the question?

Comment: Do we really need ScaleDrawable? `drawable.setBounds()` scales original drawable, so it can be used directly in `setCompoundDrawables()`

Comment: You don't need API 23 and you don't need ScaleDrawable. The drawable setBounds resize the icon directly to use in setCompoundDrawable