# How to size an Image of a button?

Tags: java, android, layout

I have the following Layout

```
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/binocular"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="search" />
```

and it looks like :

[image]

The picture is too large. I simply want to align the image to the left with the `corredct` size, so it fits with the `height` of the button.

I know I could adjust the bound of the image by code. But I would like to know, if there is a way to do with `layout` `specification`.

There is a solution mentoined : [how to change a drawableLeft icon size on a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998914/how-to-change-a-drawableleft-icon-size-on-a-button) (accepted answer)

I guess this is the correct one, but I do not understand , where to put the `layer-list` and how to reference it in the `button`.

Can someone help ?

Comment: try using imagebutton.

Comment: create a new drawable file in **res/drawable** folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create new drawable xml file and there put layer-list code. For example button_background.xml.

Then set on button this drawable

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_background"
```

Comment: Wow. Thats it. Thanks a lot. Someone downvoted yours, I upvoted your correct answer. Have to wait 10 minutes to accept. Thanks

Comment: @mcflysoft If it is correct answer you can set as corrected with check mark, to close question. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `scaleType` attribute on the `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/iconBtn"
  android:layout_width="64dip"
  android:layout_height="64dip"
  android:src="@drawable/binocular"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:background="#00000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ImageButton with these properties

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_topleft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"        
 />
```

padding plays very important role in sizing the image after `scaleType` fails.

hope this will help you.