# Resize png icon inside Android Studio / IntellIJ

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I want a way to resize png icon inside Android Studio, so that I have not resize it from external source. Please note I am not talking about to code. I want resize png icon. (Like 100*100 to 50*50)

Any plugin/ In AS way you know about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998914/how-to-change-a-drawableleft-icon-size-on-a-button

Comment: @NileshRathod please try to understand question dude.

Comment: @NileshRathod I want to resize icon hardly, like some time we need to resize png background size from 2000 dp to 1000 dp. Then we resize & compress image from external website/ paint/picture manager. You got me ?

Comment: Android studio not giving any support like png resizer. You should do it from external source.

Comment: @ChetanShelake It can be provided from some plugin, Like I use TinyPng Transform plugin to compress my images inside Android Studio.

Comment: I always forget, it is offtopic on SO. Sorry guys, I wanted to know if it exist

Answer (score 1):

If you mean resizing in code, then you need to get a bitmap from either bitmap drawable / resource stream directly.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, yourWidth, yourHeight, false)
```

This will scale your bitmap.

If you wanted to get different image size for different density, you are looking for https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer, which allows you to batch import your image file and scale your image into different sizes for different dpi.

If you are looking for editing to raw png size, you need to use external tools.