# How to change image size in EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml

I set the picture to my EditText using
android:drawableLeft
But I had a problem in the size of this picture, how can I change it in xml?

xml

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/RegisterActivity_EditText_Email"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/field_edit_text_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail_img_foreground"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Use ImageView to modify your image size.

Comment: You can go here and see the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40999237/10752944)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always cheat and use:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/field_edit_text_style">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/RegisterActivity_EditText_Email"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:background=""
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/perm_group_personal_info"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the layout_height like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/RegisterActivity_EditText_Email"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:background="@drawable/field_edit_text_style"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail_img_foreground"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/q3bxlu) I need to change the size of the image so that it fits well in the field. In the screenshot, I think it’s clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.yourdrawable);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5), 
                     (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
Button btn = findViewbyId(R.id.yourbtnID);
RegisterActivity_EditText_Email.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);

Comment: or you can create an layerlist like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/icon"
      android:width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:height="@dimen/icon_size"
      />

</layer-list >

Answer (score 0):

You just need a Linear Layout.

Add ImageView and EditText in LinearLayout and set 'layout Orientation' horizontal.

> android:orientation="horizontal"

Try below code after changing height and width accordingly.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="width"
    android:layout_height="height"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="width"
        android:layout_height="height"
        android:src="@drawable/mail_img_foreground" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/RegisterActivity_EditText_Email"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/field_edit_text_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Feel free to ask in comments. :-)