# How do I make my Android button smaller?

Tags: android

Here is my current code.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Weather"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
        style="@style/XM.ActionBar.ButtonSecondary"
        android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_weather_sunny" />
```

How do I make the entire button smaller in size? It is in a LinearLayout.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: set the width and height?

Comment: OR make the textSize smaller

Comment: Already tried. The text disappears. http://imgur.com/a/UxEmC

Comment: your need change size in java and set again check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538641/4797289)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the width and height manually instead of using `wrap_content` if you want smaller button size. 
But doing so would probably make your button too small to contain the text inside. So you probably would like to control the font size

```
<Button android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="Weather"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    style="@style/XM.ActionBar.ButtonSecondary"
    android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_weather_sunny"/>
```

Edited: textSize to sp thanks @MinnuKaAnae

Comment: textsize should be mentioned in sp not in dp

Comment: opps, sorry bout that, will edit it. thanks @MinnuKaAnae

Answer (score 0):

Change width and height to as per your requirement

```
  <Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Weather"
    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
    style="@style/XM.ActionBar.ButtonSecondary"
    android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_weather_sunny" />
```

Comment: Not working in the sense I want the entire button to be scaled down, not just the absolute size. Meaning I want the entire drawable + text size + clickable space to be smaller. http://imgur.com/a/UxEmC

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width and heigth to somthing like `40dp` each.
If it does not work, remove the theme applied :D