# Adjust drawable to fit in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable

I have the following layout:

[image]

I want to set a drawable inside my textedit, something like this:

[image]

The problem comes when I go to my EditText and I try to set `android:drawableEnd="@drawable/money"`, this happens:

[image]

How can I adjust this drawable?

Comment: use this and resize your icon. https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=add_circle&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_add_circle&theme=light&color=rgba(33%2C%20150%2C%20243%2C%200.6)

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538021/how-can-i-shrink-the-drawable-on-a-button) , it should fix your problem

Comment: @Ahmad I've implemented this and happens the same.

Comment: @KaranMer This page is amazing but it only generates on black, white or a single color.

Comment: you can use your image, select it from option next to clipart

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round_textview_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image_info" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image_info" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]