# What is the best solution for scaling 'drawable-top' inside button?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a button with a drawableTop which does not resize for different displays and get pushed out of view..

I've tried making using different layouts as buttons even attempted to use ViewTreeObserver, but noting seems to work well enough..

Result on hi-res displays (as expected)

[image]

Result on smaller displays (broken)

[image]

layout.xml

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="#31b8bf"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ble"
        android:padding="8sp"
        android:text="BLE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: Is it a PNG icon or SVG?

Comment: Where is `ble.png` located? Any chance it's inside `res/drawable-nodpi/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538641/7331042

> You should use a ImageButton and specify the image in android:src, and
>   set android:scaletype to fitXY

..or do same programmatically.