# How to make Image smaller in a button

Tags: android, eclipse, android-button

I have made a button and then added some text and an image into it however the image size is too large for the button. I would like to make the image smaller is there any way of doing this.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/curvebutton"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Mechanic"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/broke_down"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in code. As explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559083/scaling-a-drawable-inside-a-button), you can do it in the following way. I tested this code and it works.

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_face_black);// Use your image
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5),
                (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));
        ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, 90, 90);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```